# Swift: I got " Unexpectedly found nil " in "tableView.delegate=self"

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, xcode9, unwrap

I connect a segue between a button and a view controller as shown in the screenshoot.
[image: I connect a segue between a button and a view controller.]

Everything works until I choose the class as "ViewController".
[image]

Every time I click the "Add" button, the code crashes with following error:"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
[image]

I'm really confused now. Can anyone help me this?

Comment: Your table view outlet isn't connected.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for helping but I'm pretty sure that I have connected the tableView outlet.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting crash bcoz table view is not connected as `IBOutlet`.

You need to connect table view `IBOutlet` in to view controller. You can do it by assistant editor top right corner (a double circle button intersecting each other) and drag and drop by pressing right click from table view to the view controller.

Once `IBOutet` is connected, in view controller there will be a dark gray  color circle in before a property indicates that it will be connected successfully.

[image]

If circle is not filled then it means that property is not connected as `IBOutlet`.

[image]

**See pic.**

[image]

Comment: Sure! Thanks for help

Comment: After I checked my outlet, I'm pretty sure that I connect tableView correctly. It IS a dark gray color.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting crash because you did not set outlet of tableview with storyboard.
Please add outlet first and then set delegate.

Make sure while you get such crashes you must check that your control is not nil.

Comment: However, after I checked my outlets, I'm pretty sure that I connect tableView correctly

Answer (score 1):

Check that all your outlets are working on the Connections inspector, also check that you are inheriting from the classes **UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource** and everything is property connected.